# Custom View Controller on launching

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

After a few years off the grid, I'm back programming a quick iOS application and I have to say it seems I need to get back on track. :D

I'm just trying to set-up a `Login` view upon launching the application and I am stuck with the following issue on which I've read about a lot but could not fix it. Simulation stops on the `main.m` `(@autoreleasepool)`.

**FYI:** I am not using Xib or Storyboard as I'm trying to do everything programmatically.

```
libc++abi.dyLibL terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

It is probably coming from one of the following.
`LoginViewController.h`:

```
@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController 
@end
```

`Test1 / LoginViewController.m`:

I guess there should be a `init` method defined from `UIViewController` so I would not need to define one here.

```
@implementation LoginViewController
@end
```

`Test2 / LoginViewController.m`:
Trying to override with my custom `init` function. No luck as well.

```
@implementation LoginViewController
- (id) init
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
return self;
}
@end
```

`AppDelegate.m`:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController init] alloc];
// error here
self.window.rootViewController = loginViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Not sure exactly what went wrong here but it crashes right after seeing a black iPhone screen on the simulator.

Any help appreciated! ;)

Thanks.

Comment: remove the first line `self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];`

Comment: does not change anything I'm afraid.

Comment: self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; change to self = [super init];

Comment: Same issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

`LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController init] alloc];`

To

`LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];`

Comment: I don't even know what to say ... Now it works. Like I said I really need to get back into it ... Thanks a lot! I'll accept as answer as soon as it's allowed.